# Can gravity be measured by proximity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, geophysics

Can the topography of a terrain be measured by a gravimeter to give a clear image of the surface or sub-surface of a planet or does gravity scatter like light? In other words can the changes in gravity create a 3 dimensional picture of an object if close enough. The picture is speculation of how distance using gravimeters may be used to map the ground and possibly caves. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scattering like light is not relevant, because we're looking at the non-radiative near-field solution (also: it's static).

The GRACE mission and its follow on (https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/Grace/index.html) used/uses precision metrology between two satellites flying in formation to reconstruct mass distributions on Earth, with phenomenal resolution.

Submarine-borne precision graviometers have been used for both bathymetry and navigation.

In your drawing, if the satellite track is supposed to represent the equipotential surface, then the deviations shown are inverted. The theoretical mean-sea-level equipotential surface of the Earth is known as "The Geoid". EGM96 is a full multipole expansion out to $l=360$, and the most recent unclassified version, EGM08 (https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/) goes to an order of a few thousand, but doesn't use all the $m$-values.

If look at the geoid over a mass void, such as the Mariana Trench, it dips down, while a mass excess, such as the island of Hawaii, brings sea level (and the geoid) up. It may be counter intuitive that lesser gravity pulls you down further, but the potential is defined as negative energy relative to zero at infinite distance, hence you need to travel to smaller radii to get to the same potential.

That's a bit abstract. It turns out, the vertical deflection of local $g$ is also a thing that is measured and made available to scientists (https://geodesy.noaa.gov/GEOID/DEFLEC96/readme.txt). If you imagine surfaces that are orthogonal to the deflection around mass deficits/excesses, it is pretty obvious which way the geoid goes.

Finally, there is also the Mars equipotential surface, called the Aeroid, which is computed from satellite tracking and LIDAR elevation measurements. Since Mars was clobbered by a huge impactor, it has an enormous quadruple moment. It really is pear shaped, with the norther hemisphere being low and flat, and the southern hemisphere being at much higher elevation (hence early landers went to the north, where there's enough atmosphere to apply the brakes).

Venus also has a known geoid, derived primarily from the Magellan orbit and synthetic aperture radar imaging of the surface.